# Branching process and posterior distribution.

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I have the following branching process:

[image]

(*I added the $Z$'s myself for the number of individuals in each gen, hope it's correct.*)

> Assume the offspring distribution is Poisson with expectation
> $\lambda$ and also assume that we use an improper prior
> $\pi(\lambda)\propto_{\lambda}1/\lambda$ for $\lambda$. Using the
> information in the figure, compute the posterior distribution for
> $\lambda.$

Using Baye's theorem with an observed count $k$, I get

$$\pi(\lambda|k)\propto_{\lambda}\pi(k|\lambda)\pi(\lambda)\propto_{\lambda}e^{-\lambda}\cdot\lambda^{k}\cdot\frac{1}{\lambda}=e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{k-1}.$$

So we see that this posterior is $\pi(\lambda|k)\sim\Gamma(\lambda;k,1).$

However, how do I know what $k$ is based on the figure?

Comment: Assuming the next generations of the tree are not represented in the figure (not that they are empty), the figure tells you that the numbers of offspring for this tree are, starting from the root, $$1,\ 2,\ 3,\ 2,\ 0,\ 0,\ 1,\ 4,\ 2$$ hence the posterior knowing this tree is $$\pi(\lambda\mid k)\propto\pi(\lambda)\prod_k\pi(k\mid\lambda)$$ that is, $$\pi(\lambda\mid k)\propto\lambda^{-1}(e^{-\lambda}\lambda)(e^{-\lambda}\lambda^2)(e^{-\lambda}\lambda^3)(e^{-\lambda}\lambda^2)(e^{-\lambda}\lambda^0)(e^{-\lambda}\lambda^0)(e^{-\lambda}\lambda^1)(e^{-\lambda}\lambda^4)(e^{-\lambda}\lambda^2)$$

Comment: ...or, more simply, $$\pi(\lambda\mid k)\propto e^{-9\lambda}\lambda^{14}$$ Assuming the next generations are empty, one arrives at $$\pi(\lambda\mid k)\propto e^{-16\lambda}\lambda^{14}$$

Comment: @Did Thank you for the answer. Could you elaborate on what you mean by empty and non empty generation? I also don't see how you obtained the number of offsprings? How did you find $1,2,3,2,0,0,1,4,2$?

Comment: I looked at each node and counted its descendants.

Comment: @ Did Okay I understnad that now. So can one then say that $$\pi(\lambda|k)\sim\Gamma(\lambda;15,9)?$$

Comment: Sorry but you definitely should know that...